# Density In The Theorem/Proof of The Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, approximation-theory

Yet again, I have a question that I could use some help with. Note that almost everything can be found in C. Pugh's, *Real Mathematical Analysis* (soft-cover, 2nd Edition, ISBN: 978-1-4419-2941-9); furthermore, although it is a book-preview, what I'm about to refer to as well as question can (hopefully, as it did for me) be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=2NVJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=Stone-Weierstrass%20Theorem%20in%20C.%20Pugh%27s,%20Real%20Mathematical%20Analysis&source=bl&ots=ZN6M014xZb&sig=3iVgrZ1kgfHgiE6y2MfKLZBdEhk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8oo3r9_zJAhVELyYKHYRCDHYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Stone-Weierstrass%20Theorem%20in%20C.%20Pugh%27s%2C%20Real%20Mathematical%20Analysis&f=false).

My question concerns the very beginning of the proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem in Pugh's book (proof of Theorem 19, PG. 224 in the actual book, or PG. 235 in the book-preview link above). The theorem from the text is restated below.

> **Stone-Weierstrass Theorem:** If $M$ is a compact metric space, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a function algebra in $C^{0}M$ that vanishes nowhere and separates points, then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C^{0}M$.

As far as the definitions of a function algebra, the function algebra vanishing at a point $p\in M$, as well as the function algebra separating points in $M$, please see the link above (they are available in the preview for me, but I omitted them for the sake of saving space - I will gladly state them if need be). Moreover, for some compact metric space $M$, $C^{0}M$ is shorthand notation for the set $C^{0}\big(M,\mathbb{R}\big)=\big\{ \phi~|~\phi:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~\phi\text{ is continuous on }M\big\}$, i.e., $C^{0}M$ is the set of continuous, real-valued functions on the compact metric space $M$.

Now for my question. In the very beginning of Pugh's proof of the theorem above, we assume $\mathcal{A}\subset C^{0}M$ is a function algebra that vanishes nowhere and separates points (clearly),  Then, we show $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C^{0}M$, to which the proof asserts that this can be shown by proving for any $F\in C^{0}M$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $G\in\mathcal{A}$ such that for all $x\in M$ we have $F(x)-\varepsilon<G(x)<F(x)+\varepsilon$ (equivalently, $\big|G(x)-F(x)\big|=\big|F(x)-G(x)\big|<\varepsilon$). Now, earlier in the book -- which isn't part of the book-preview for me, unfortunately (if it helps, the definition is on PG. 98 in Pugh's text) -- Pugh defines density of a set which is restated below (I added the ambient topological space part for reference purposes).

> **Definition:** Let $M$ be a metric (or topological) space. If $S\subset M$ and $\overline{S}=M$, then $S$ is ***dense*** in $M$.

I've been trying to connect the statement at the beginning of the Stone-Weierstrass proof with this definition above. In other words, in the proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem in Pugh's text, we need to show that $\overline{\mathcal{A}}=C^{0}M$, correct? Furthermore, how does this translate to, or how do we connect this definition with, for any $F\in C^{0}M$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $G\in\mathcal{A}$ such that for all $x\in M$ we have $F(x)-\varepsilon<G(x)<F(x)+\varepsilon$?

First I started working with the fact that (where this can be shown) $\lim\mathcal{A}=\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ where $\lim\mathcal{A}$ is the limit set of the function algebra $\mathcal{A}$ (i.e., the set of limit points of $\mathcal{A}$). Then, I recalled the example that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ being equivalent to saying that for any pair of distinct real numbers $p<r\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a rational number $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $p<q<r$.

I'm thinking that I'm on the right track by going from the example that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$; and the connection I'm trying to make is possibly similar to showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to saying that for some $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, $p<q<r$ whenever $p<r\in\mathbb{R}$...just in a more abstract scene?

In sum, any help with making this connection will be greatly appreciated. I apologize that this is a bit lengthy but I wanted to be precise. As a personal remark, check out the proof, as it is pretty neat - especially how he finds a functions that supersolves the expression $F(x)-\varepsilon<G(x)<F(x)+\varepsilon$.

Comment: The space $C^0 M$, equipped with the supremum norm $\| f\| = \sup_x |f(x)|$, is a normed space. Then the density of $\mathcal{A}$ is with respect to the resulting topology.

Comment: @SangchulLee : Thank you for your comment. See me comment below in terms of my mix-up; essentially I made things to hard on myself when trying to wrap myself around Pugh's assertion in his proof. In any case, I knew that the connection highly depends on the fact that we use the subspace metric coupled with $\mathcal{A}$, and that there had to be an easier way than using a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{A}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for all $x$ you have $F(x)-\varepsilon<G_{\varepsilon}(x)<F(x)+\varepsilon$(as you noted this is the same as $\lVert F-G_{\varepsilon} \rVert<\varepsilon$)  for any epsilon then $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}G_{\varepsilon}=F$, so $F$ is indeed a limit point. Since $F$ was arbitrary we get $\lim\mathcal{A}=F$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up! What started everything is that there was a proof I did that uses the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. I, coincidentally, used almost the same argument you posted above -- overall, I wasn't sure if I was correct. I kept thinking since WNTS $\lim\mathcal{A}=\overline{\mathcal{A}}=C^{0}(M,R)$, then I would have to choose a sequence $(F_{n})_{_{n\geq 1}}$ so that the equivalent statement stems from $F_{n}\rightrightarrows F$, as $n\rightarrow+\infty$. Then I realized that I didn't quite clearly/rigorously understand Pugh's proof in the first place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at the result is to start with $C^0M$ is a metric space with the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in M}|f(x)-g(x)|$. Then, we want to say that $\mathscr A$ is dense in $C^0M$, so we want $C^0M=\overline{\mathscr A}$.

In other words, we want to show that every $F\in C^0M$ is a point of $\mathscr A$ or a limit point of $\mathscr A$. To say that $F\in C^0M$ is a limit point of $\mathscr A$, with the language of the metric, is to say that for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $G\in \mathscr A$ such that $d(F,G)=|F(x)-G(x)|<\varepsilon$ $(x\in M)$, and that's just what Pugh does.